# Delayed job wont start using Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, delayed-job

I cannot start delayed job process using a capistrano recipe. Here's the error I am getting.

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-2.1.1/lib/delayed/command.rb:62:in `mkdir': File exists - /my_app/server/releases/20101120001612/tmp/pids (Errno::EEXIST)
```

Here's the capistrano code (NOTE-: I have tried both start/restart commands)

```
after "deploy:restart", "delayed_job:start"
task :start, :roles => :app do          
  run "cd #{current_path}; RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} script/delayed_job -n 2 start"
end
```

More detail errors from deployment logs -

```
executing command
 [err :: my_server] /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-2.1.1/lib/delayed/command.rb:62:in `mkdir': File exists - /my_app/server/releases/20101120001612/tmp/pids (Errno::EEXIST)
 [err :: my_server] from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-2.1.1/lib/delayed/command.rb:62:in `daemonize'
 [err :: my_server] from script/delayed_job:5:in `<main>'
    command finished
failed: "sh -c 'cd /my_app/server/current; RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job -n 3 restart'" on myserevr
```

This is a Rails 3 app (**v3.0.3**)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I fixed the issue, I passed an explicit pids dir parameter using "--pid-dir". Not sure if this is perfect, but it worked.

```
task :restart, :roles => :app do
  run "cd #{current_path}; RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} script/delayed_job -n #{dj_proc_count} --pid-dir=#{app_root}/shared/dj_pids restart"
end
```

Answer (score 21):

Seeing the same problem.

It turns out I was missing the `~/apps/application_name/shared/pids` directory.

Finally creating it made this problem go away.

No need to set up custom `dj_pids` directory.

Answer (score 10):

I also got this error and found a couple of issues:

- Ensure you have a `shared/pids` folder.
- Ensure you have the correct hooks setup

Your deploy.rb script should contain:

```
require "delayed/recipes"

after "deploy:stop", "delayed_job:stop"
after "deploy:start", "delayed_job:start"
after "deploy:restart", "delayed_job:restart"
```

I'd copied the hooks from an old post and they appear to be incorrect now. These are from the actual delayed_job recipe file comments.

I believe `cap deploy:setup` should create the `pids` folder but I set things up a different way and it was not created. `app/current/tmp/pids` links to `app/shared/pids` and this was causing the false directory exists error.

Comment: Same here. Happened when using capistrano's little-known `shared_children` setting. Solved by symlinking in shared: `ln -s tmp/pids`.

Comment: @Zubin, @wallerjake and @PhilT: i think i have the same symlinking-problem:
`current/tmp/pids -> /var/www/apps/production.myserver.de/shared/pids`
so do i have to go to the `/var/www/apps/production.myserver.de/shared`-directory and enter the `ln -s tmp/pids`-command? I'm not really firm in Unix-commands :( 
thank you!

Comment: ok the only thing which i have to do was to create the `pids`-directory in `/var/www/apps/production.myserver.de/shared` :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the creation of this directory before

```
after "deploy:restart", "delayed_job:start"
task :start, :roles => :app do  
  run "mkdir #{current_path}/tmp/pids"
  run "cd #{current_path}; RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} script/delayed_job -n 2 start"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Turned out that there was an existing

> application_name/shared/pids/delayed_job.main.pid

file, which had incorrect owner permissions, which was causing the deployment to fail. Fixing this file's permissions solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since the creation of the directories is cheap and fast, use the following callback:

```
before 'deploy', 'deploy:setup'
```

This will ensure that structure is always there before each deploy.