# Capistrano task can't find gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

Deploying with Capistrano 2.15.5 works fine, except for one task that runs after deploy to restart the DelayedJob worker.

It tells me:

```
Could not find addressable-2.3.6 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
...
failed: "sh -c 'RAILS_ENV=production /home/docs/apps/myapp/current/bin/delayed_job restart'"
```

The gem is installed, however. When I copy and paste that command on the server, it runs fine.

Here are the relevant-seeming sections of my deploy.rb:

```
set :user, 'same-user-that-can-execute-commands-successfully-on-server'

set :use_sudo, false

after "deploy:cleanup", "deploy:restart_dj"

namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
  task :restart_dj, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "RAILS_ENV=production #{File.join(current_path,'bin','delayed_job')} restart"
  end
end
```

Comment: try to run that `restart_dj` task after `deploy:restart` but not `cleanup` and see whether it is working or not

Comment: @anusha Unfortunately that does not work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting the same error ? and also give some "puts" statements in that task whether it is calling or not

Comment: @anusha It's still producing the same error. It is indeed calling that task. I've also verified it's using the same linux user that can normally run that command. I think it may not be executing the command within the right directory, which is why it can't find the Gemfile. Also, when I just try to run a rake command containing the same command, it says it can't find the rakefile, so I don't think it's in the rails app directory at all. However, preceding the command with 'cd /path/to/app/current &&' does not work; any other suggestions?

Comment: try chnging the command like this `  run "cd #{current_path}; RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} script/delayed_job -n #{dj_proc_count} --pid-dir=#{app_root}/shared/dj_pids restart"` and check once. please refer this link:`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230577/delayed-job-wont-start-using-capistrano`